# Yii Cdbcommand Failed To Execute With Sql Server only in insert

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

I am using Yii with SQL SERVER

When i inserting data it shows a error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier..
>   The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_acc_appTokens]
>   ([TockenKey], [UserProfileId], [ClientId], [Expired], [CreatedDate])
>   VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)

In My controler

```
$newApp = new AppTokens();
     $newApp->UserProfileId = 'profileId;
     $newApp->ClientId = 'ClientId';
     $newApp->Expired = 900;
     $newApp->CreatedDate = '2013-03-22';
     $newApp->TockenKey = 'tokey_key';                                  
     $newApp->save();
```

Actually select statements working fine . I don't know what the problem with insert . Please suggest me

Comment: The error message is not just for show... you have an `uniqueidentifier` column, but the value you tried to insert into it does not match the format SQL Server accepts for that data type.

Comment: I tried with only field . But it shows the same error

Comment: @DCoder I got it but how to change it to uniqueidentifier.